# Create pandas new columns based on rows category + convert rows into column - in groupby method

Tags: pandas, dataframe, group-by

The dataset I'm working with is as follows. I'd want to add new columns to the table based on the row classifications. At the same time, I'd want to have only one row every month. I'm not sure if I should use groupby or not.

```
Year    Month   Index   Humidity    Temperature Pressure        date
2019    1       High    100%            30 °C   1021 mbar       20191
2019    1       Low     28%             9 °C    1011 mbar       20191
2019    1       Average 65%             21 °C   1016 mbar       20191
2019    2       High    100%            32 °C   1020 mbar       20192
2019    2       Low     28%             10 °C   1008 mbar       20192
2019    2       Average 63%             18°C    1014 mbar       20192
```

So the output value looks like this:

```
**Desired output**

Year    Month   HighHumidity    LowHumidity AverageHumidity HighTemperature LowTemperature  AverageTemperature  HighPressure    LowPressure     AveragePressure     date
2019      1         100%            28%         65%             30 °C               9 °C        21 °C           1021 mbar           1011 mbar       1016 mbar       20191
2019      2         100%            27%         63%             32 °C               10 °C       18 °C           1020 mbar           1008 mbar       1014 mbar       20192
```

I experimented with the following code. However, the index column works with all other columns, however I only want to use particular columns in this operation.:

```
df = df.pivot(index='date', columns=['Index'])
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[1], col[0])) for col in df.columns]

        Average_Year    High_Year   Low_Year    Average_Month   High_Month  Low_Month   Average_Humidity    High_Humidity   Low_Humidity    Average_Temperature High_Temperature    Low_Temperature Average_Pressure    High_Pressure   Low_Pressure
date                                                            
20191   2019                2019    2019            1                   1       1           65%                 100%            28%             21 °C               30 °C               9 °C            1016 mbar           1021 mbar   1011 mbar
201910  2019                2019    2019            10                  10      10          81%                 100%            49%             29 °C               35 °C               22 °C           1011 mbar           1016 mbar   1007 mbar
201911  2019                2019    2019            11                  11      11          77%                 100%            49%             26 °C               33 °C               16 °C           1013 mbar           1017 mbar   1006 mbar
201912  2019                2019    2019            12                  12      12          77%                 100%            38%             21 °C               31 °C               10 °C           1016 mbar           1021 mbar   1012 mbar
20192   2019                2019    2019            2                   2       2           65%                 100%            28%             23 °C               32 °C               10 °C           1015 mbar           1020 mbar   1008 mbar
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add `Year` and `Month` to parameter `index`:

```
df = df.pivot(index=['Year','Month','date'], columns=['Index'])
df.columns = ['_'.join((col[1], col[0])) for col in df.columns]
df = df.reset_index()

#for correct order date column
df['date'] = df.pop('date')
print (df)
   Year  Month Average_Humidity High_Humidity Low_Humidity  \
0  2019      1              65%          100%          28%   
1  2019      2              63%          100%          28%   

  Average_Temperature High_Temperature Low_Temperature Average_Pressure  \
0                21°C             30°C             9°C         1016mbar   
1                18°C             32°C            10°C         1014mbar   

  High_Pressure Low_Pressure   date  
0      1021mbar     1011mbar  20191  
1      1020mbar     1008mbar  20192
```